# How to prevent form auto-fill software/browser extensions (e.g. Dashlane) from interfering on HTML elements' styles?

Tags: css, styled-components, autofill

I'm developing a TypeScript/ReactJS front-end for a project of mine, and noticed Dashlane, my personal data manager, interfering on a customized `Input` component display.

In this below example, Dashlane auto-fills the form, changing the background color of an HTML `<input>` tag inside the `Input` component, and resulting in unexpected behavior of the application.

A field that was supposed to look like this:

[image]

Is displayed like this:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent these personal data managers, not just Dashlane, but all form auto-fill software/browser extensions from interfering on a React application display behavior? I want the user to be able to use these extensions, but I don't want them modifying the styles on my page.

**-- Update --**

As @lawrence-witt asked, here are the styles applied to the element before and after filling the field with Dashlane:

```
#before {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab",serif;
  flex: 1;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: #f4ede8;
}

#after {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab",serif;
  flex: 1;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 204);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Can we get a comparison of the brower inspector output with/without the extension installed? I.e. how is Dashlane injecting these styles into the page? It will probably just be a case of overridng it in your own styles with the css `!important` rule if they are being injected inline.

Comment: @lawrence-witt yeah, Dashlane does inject two declarations setting the `background-color` and `color` properties. Using `!important` on my styles solved the problem. 

I finished this project quite a while ago, but thinking about it now this was a pretty obvious solution. Anyway, thank you very much for responding. I'm gonna update the question with the inspected styles and if you want to write an answer I'll be happy to accept it.