# How to prevent style injection by third party browser extensions on a web app

Tags: css, dom-manipulation, browser-extension

As I mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61384976/12175965), I noticed Dashlane's Google Chrome extension modifying the styles on my web app when using their auto-fill functionality.

Setting the CSS properties of interest as `!important` prevented the injected styles from being effectively displayed. But I was wandering if there is a way to prevent these extensions from injecting styles on existing elements on the page in the first place.

I think is important to point out the word 'existing' because some of these extensions might have to add and manipulate their own elements in order to work properly. But I don't want them interfering with anything that I've created.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but a word of caution that people using your site may have very good reasons to override styles, such as to improve its accessibility or increase contrast or what-have-you. MDN has a good blurb about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/CSS_and_JavaScript#accept_that_users_can_override_styles

Comment: Of course, it's your discretion, in which case `!important` conveys precisely what you want, that this should be the element's final style.

Comment: If the question is how to _completely_ prevent extensions from modifying page styles, I don't think there's any way around it. Content scripts can do pretty much whatever they want to the DOM, including modifying element `style` attributes, and even closed-mode shadow DOM can probably be bypassed by a content script executed at document start (see the top highlight on [this article](https://blog.revillweb.com/open-vs-closed-shadow-dom-9f3d7427d1af) for an example of how, though this may not be a concern due to content scripts and the document not directly sharing globals).